# I can't access my now-turned https apache webserver on other external devices rather than the webserver's host itself

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https, webserver

I had just been able to finish and remove that dreaded warning from my browser of my local site's unsecured connection. But as I try to access it on my phone through the IP address of my Webserver host, it just wouldn't load. If I remove the the "s" from "https" - so instead it being, "http" only - it would just give a bad request error. I can't figure it out.

Does it have to do to the CA Certificates? I have already installed that on my phone. Do I need to like do some hacky port forwarding on the router? My phone's browser would just be stuck loading, and there would be no responses whatsoever. It feels like it's trying to find the IP domain outside of the local network.

I'm not really, really an expert about networking, guys. I just did it on a whim earlier and was able to do the tip of the iceberg, I guess.

EDIT: Just say if it's really not possible to access https website anymore on an intranet environment. I can access the site when I remove the SSL configurations: SSLEngine, SSLCertificateKey, and SSLCertificateKeyFile. So, I am saying that is it not possible to just access an https website through your local network, which in this case, the browser just lookup the IP Address on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an internal pki for your lan, generate a root CA, sign an intermediate and issue a certificate for your local domain.
At this point you can install your root and intermediate certificates on your lan pc and the connection will be shown as trusted. Keep in mind that a browser like chrome, edge or firefox might ignore the PC pki and use its own: in this case you have to install your rootCA and intermediate into the browser pki.

Alternatively, if you have valid ssl certificate (for example a let's encrypt one), you just need to configure your dns server to resolve the domain you want to connect to, with the private ip of the web server in your lan that's hosting it.

If you want to use an ssl certificate to access a domain by its ip (something like https://1.2.3.4) you're doing it wrong and you should fix it using a real domain name.